# Nonnegative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square non-negative irreducible matrix of order $n$ whose spectral radius $r(A)=1$. Let $u,v$ be positive vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Au=u$ and $A'v=v$ and $v'u=1$ and let $B=A-uv'$.
Then show that:

1. nonzero eigenvalues of B belongs to the spectrum of A but $1$ does not belong to the spectrum of $B$;
2. $\lim (B+B^2+B^3+.......+B^m)/m=0$ where $m$ tends to infinity.

I have been able to show the first part by considering the matrix $(I-uv')$ which is idempotent but yet need to prove second part

Answer (score 0):

The problem statements in both part 1 and part 2 are false. The correct statements should be

1. $\ 1\notin\sigma(B)\setminus\{0\}\subset\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}$.
2. $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(B+B^2+\ldots+B^m\right)=(I-B)^{-1}-I$.

Comment: I think the second part you are pointing out is a general identity..and I think it may not happen in this case. And I have edited the problem .

Comment: @sayak Since you have edited the question, do you see the answer now?